# SQL syntax without inner join or join keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to use this query without inner join keyword

```
select 
    MAIN_ACCOUNTS.MAIN_ID, sum(voucher.AMOUNT_US) "Total Amount"
from 
    MAIN_ACCOUNTS 
inner join 
    SUB_ACCOUNTS on MAIN_ACCOUNTS.MAIN_ID = SUB_ACCOUNTS.MAIN_ID
inner join 
    Voucher on SUB_ACCOUNTS.SUB_ID = Voucher.credit_ACCOUNT_ID
group by 
    MAIN_ACCOUNTS.MAIN_ID ;
```

Comment: Why? ???????????????????

Comment: so remove the inner join?

Comment: Seriously why is it always the Oracle users who won't use the Join syntax???????? Let me guess, the old DBA in the closet told you it was "faster without the JOIN"? Between that and teachers using the comma syntax we're going to have a broken generation of SQL users.

Comment: `inner` is not required, you can just remove it.

Comment: @JacobH: there are a lot of people who claim that there are still bugs in Oracle's implementation of the explicit `JOIN` operator. Even though those bug existed (back in Oracle 9 and to a certain extend in 10g as well), they have always been very narrow edge cases and mostly related to the use inside a materialize views. Still those guys insist that even then the explicit JOINs should never be used. I too find that pretty stupid and - even though being an "Oracle user" - have always recommended to use explicit joins over the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins

Answer (score 3):

That would be

```
select ma.main_id, sum(v.amount_us) 
from main_accounts ma, sub_accounts sa, voucher v
where sa.main_id = ma.main_id
  and v.credit_account_id = sa.sub_id
group by ma.main_id;
```

Believe or not, but ANSI join causes problems in some (older) Oracle software products, such as Reports Developer 10g (9.0.4) - not that it won't work, Reports crashes. So - sometimes you're just doomed to use it.

On the other hand, yes - *older* people might need some time to adjust to "new" syntax (right, *new*; available since when exactly? 1990's?).

There are two major advantages I see:

- code is (really) easier to read - joins *here*, conditions *there*
- outer join, using the "old" Oracle syntax & its (+) operator, makes it impossible to outer join one table to more than only one another table

So, in my opinion, you (the OP) should use ANSI join whenever you can.

Comment: The "new" syntax is part of the SQL:1992 standard - it's been around for ***26 YEARS*** now - this is *no longer new* ......

Comment: That's exactly what I've said, @marc.

Comment: And implicit, comma separated joins, are valid ANSI SQL. Still in SQL-2016, not deprecated.

Comment: @jarlh, I presume Oracle will keep it - as an option - *forever*, for backward compatibility. Imagine that 20c (some imaginary future version) removes support for such joins - at least half of the whole Oracle world wouldn't be able to migrate to a higher database version without serious rewriting of their code.